# Devise multiple model, fullname = nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I use `devise` gem on my application.
I created 2 models (to have two different registration forms).

But when I added fullname and name to my forms via db. It sends me nil when registering or changing the profile. Everything else works perfectly.

**user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

**editor.rb**

```
class Editor < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :softwares
end
```

**controller/editors/registrations_controller.rb**

```
class Editors::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
end
```

**controller/users/registrations_controller.rb**

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
end
```

**db/migrate/devise_create_users.rb**

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|

    t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
    t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""
    t.string :name
    t.string :fullname 

   end
  end
end
```

Same thing for editors

Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope it will solve your problem...

**controller/editors/registrations_controller.rb**

```
class Editors::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  private

  def sign_up_params
    params.require(:editor).permit(:name, :fullname, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end

  def account_update_params
    params.require(:editor).permit(:name, :fullname, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
  end
end
```

**controller/users/registrations_controller.rb**

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  private

  def sign_up_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :fullname, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end

  def account_update_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :fullname, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
  end
end
```

And add this line in your config/routes.rb file

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' }
devise_for :editors, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' }
```

To learn more [click here](https://jacopretorius.net/2014/03/adding-custom-fields-to-your-devise-user-model-in-rails-4.html)